Natbib: cite author, year and number
I'm working on my thesis and I have to cite multiple times the same article. I have a code similar to this one:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sort,comma,super]{natbib}

\begin{document}

This is a citation from \citet{citation}.
Another citation.\citet{citation}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}

That gives:

This is a bit redundant since I already said that 'Smith et al.' is the first reference in bibliography. Furthermore I would like to also show the year of publishing (2024), when citing the article. Then, I want something like this:

I read the natbib docs but I didn't find anything that completely suit my problem, there is the keyword 'authoryear' to print both author name and year, but then the bibliography number is hidden.
